# Struct pointer parameters

Tags: c, structure

I'm having some trouble to move in my struct without rewrite it,

```
typedef struct listaC {
int coluna;
float valor;
struct listaC *prox;
} *Colunas;

typedef struct listaL {
    int linha;
    Colunas lcol;
struct listaL *prox;
} *Mat;
```

in my function im trying to add 2 Matrix

```
void addTo (Mat *m1, Mat m2){
    if(m2==NULL) return;
    if(m1==NULL) m1 = &m2;
    while(*m1!=NULL)
    {
        while((*m1)->lcol!=NULL)
        (*m1)->lcol->valor += m2->lcol->valor;
        m2->lcol=m2->lcol->prox;
    //here  m1->lcol = &((*m1)->lcol->prox);
    }
    m2 =m2->prox;
    m1 = &((*m1)->prox);
    *m1 = *m1->prox;
}
```

but I get an error at

```
m1->lcol = &((*m1)->lcol->prox);
```

error: request for member 'lcol' in something not a structure or union
   m1->lcol = &((*m1)->lcol->prox);

how should I fix this?

Comment: Never hide pointers behind typedefs. Most likely it is the root of all your problems.

Comment: Do not confuse your self by naming different things too similar.

Answer (score 1):

`m1` is a pointer to Mat, so a pointer to pointer to struct. The right side of the assignement is correct but the left side is lacking a dereferencement:

```
(*m1)->lcol = (*m1)->lcol->prox;
```

I also removed the `&` taking address from right side because prox is already a pointer.

Comment: wont it rewrite teh content pointed by the pointer like this?, cuz i need to preserve the matrix

Comment: @RyzonPT: Your function actually tries to add the second matrix to the first one. This answer only fixes the syntax error.

Comment: yeah but i want to change the address of the pointer so i can "move" in the struct without destroying it, i usualy do m=&((*m)->prox); this works but whent i try m->lcol=&((*m)->lcol->prox); it doesent.. thats my question...

Comment: @RyzonPT: you are right, the algo is flawed. You will need temp variables to avoid changing `(*m1)->col` and `m2->col` - same problem arise for `m2`

Comment: can u give me an example pls?

Answer (score 0):

For

```
m1->lcol = &((*m1)->lcol->prox);
```

For left side, m1 is a pointer to a pointer. To use the -> you need to be a pointer.

```
(*m1)->lcol
```

In addition on the right side the & makes it the address of the pointer to prox, when you want the just pointer itself.

```
(*m1)->lcol = ((*m1)->lcol->prox);
```

On other points, the while(*m1!=NULL) is prbally a endless loop, as m1 never cheches one you get into the loop

Comment: m1 is a pointer to Map, which is itself a typedef for pointer to struct. So m1 is a pointer to pointer to struct...

Answer (score 0):

The added complexity in syntax made you forget to dereference your variable m1 on the left hand side of the assignment.

```
m1->lcol = &((*m1)->lcol->prox);      // causes the error m1 is a ListaL**
(*m1)->lcol = &((*m1)->lcol->prox);   // this should compile.
```

Also, I think I'm spotting a bug in this line of code.  Since m1 is a linked list, and add does not change the order of the rows and columns, but only their contents, wouldn't changing anything to the link pointers introduce errors?

```
// this would make add look something like this:

// void add(Mat *m1, Mat m2)  why the added * complexity.
void add(Mat m1, Mat m2)
{
  struct listaL* proxL1;
  struct listaL* proxL2;
  struct listaC* proxC1;
  struct listaC* proxC2;

  if(m2==NULL) return;
  //if(m1==NULL) m1 = &m2; // Appropriate here?  Is this the right 
                           // place to do this?  Not part of add
                           // definition.. no return, so effect is 
                           // *m1 = m2 = 2.m2 
                           // you should consider simply passing a Mat
                           // and checking for NULL
  if (m1 == NULL) return; 

  for (proxL1 = m1, proxL2 = m2; 
       proxL1 != 0 && proxL2 != 0; 
       proxL1 = proxL1->prox, proxL2 = proxL2->prox)
  {
    for (proxC1 = proxL1->lcol, proxC2 = proxL2->lcol;
         proxC1 != 0  && proxC2 != 0; 
         proxC1 = proxC1->prox, proxC2 = proxC2->prox)
    {
      proxC1->valor += proxC2->valor;
    }
  }
  // values have been added.... done!  
}
```

I think you should only try to do the multiplication in the morning after a good night's sleep and strong coffee :)

Hint:  maybe a linked list is not the best idea for Matrices, and a simple malloc'ed array of <strike>double</strike> float could do the trick?

something like this would be much simpler to deal wuith, no?

```
typedef struct Mat 
{
  int rows;
  int cols;
  float data[1];
};
// useful for random access
#define MAT_AT(m, r, c) ((m)->data + ((r) * (m)->cols) + (c))
// useful for malloc, copy
#define MAT_SIZEOF(r, c) (sizeof(struct Mat) + (sizeof(float) * (((r) * (c)) - 1)))

// makes for an api that is much faster and efficient

struct Mat* matalloc(int r, int c)
{
  struct Mat* m = (struct Mat*)malloc(MAT_SIZEOF(r, c));
  if (m == 0) return 0;
  m->rows = r;
  m->cols = c;
  memset(m->data, 0, sizeof(float) * r * c); 
  return m
}

void matfree(struct Mat* m)
{
  free(m);
}

struct Mat* matadd(struct Mat* r, struct Mat* a, struct Mat* b)
{
  int i, j;
  assert(a && b && r 
         && a->rows == b->rows && a->cols == b->cols 
         && a->rows == r->rows && a->cols == r->cols);
  for (i = 0; i < a->rows; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < a->cols; ++j)
      *MAT_AT(r, i, j) = *MAT_AT(a, i, j) + *MAT_AT(b, i, j);
  return r;
}

struct Mat* mataddto(struct Mat* r, struct Mat* a)
{
  return matadd(r, r, a);
}
```